# Subordinating conjunctions "who" & "when" as subject clause?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, clauses, when, who

I understand *who* and *when* can be used to introduce adjective clause for sure like the following sentences.

> The time when it is good for us to meet has not been decided.
>
> The person who is qualified for the job will be appointed soon.

However, can subordinating conjunctions *who* and *when* be used to introduce subject clause?

For example,

> (1) [When it is good for us to meet] has not been decided.
> OR
> (2) [Who is qualified for the job] will be appointed soon.

Are the two sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: Add the *-ever* maybe. "Who**ever** is qualified for the job will be appointed."

Comment: Generally, the "dummy *it*" comes in in such cases: "**It** has not been decided (as to) when is good for us to meet."

Comment: See also, [ell.se]

Comment: The bracketed elements in 1) and (2) are not clauses. They are NPs in fused relative constructions. But you need "whenever" and "whoever", as in "Whenever is good for us to meet" / "Whoever is qualified for the job", where the -_ever_ phrase marks the NPs as non-referential.

Comment: ... and _who_ and _where_ are not subordinating conjunctions.

Comment: @BillJ: *Whenever is good for us to meet has not been decided* doesn't work either.

Answer (score -2):

### Short Answer

Are the two sentences grammatically correct? No, they are ungrammatical as you intend them to be.

### Long Answer

First things first, 'parts of speech' (aka, 'word class') such as 'adjective' are originally used to classify **words** based on their grammatical functions, but not to classify **phrases** or **clauses** based on their grammatical functions.

You *can* classify phrases using 'parts of speech' such as 'noun phrase', 'adjective phrase', 'verb phrase', etc. But this classification of phrases is not based on their grammatical function but on what part of speech the head of a phrase is classified as.

For example, if you classify a phrase as an adjective phrase, it's not because its grammatical function is similar to that of an adjective but because the head of the phrase is classified as an adjective:

> *I have a train **to catch**.* [Here, ***to catch*** is not an adjective phrase but a verb phrase.]
>
> *I'm **afraid of him**.* [Here, ***afraid of him*** is an adjective phrase.]

Now, turning to clauses, the head of a clause is always a verb (except for verbless clauses). Therefore, I'm afraid it'd wrong to classify your clauses as 'adjective clauses' simply because the clauses have a postmodifying function that is not even exclusive to 'adjective', as in:

> *The time **when is good for us to meet** has not been decided.*
>
> *The person **who is qualified for the job** will be appointed soon.*

Suffice it to say they are relative clauses.

Now the examples you ask the question about are:

> (1) ***When is good for us to meet** has not been decided.*
>
> (2) ***Who is qualified for the job** will be appointed soon.*

If (1) is to be a natural sentence, the boldfaced portion has to be an interrogative clause, where ***When*** is an interrogative word as in *When is good for us to meet?*
But this interpretation doesn't seem to be what you have intended.

(2), on the other hand, cannot work as is, however you interpret it, because here the boldfaced portion cannot even work as an interrogative clause due to the meaning of the main clause *will be appointed soon*.

Comment: Firstly, you’re describing modern linguistic terminology. In traditional grammar, it is perfectly legitimate to refer to clauses that modify noun phrases as adjective clauses (= headed relative clauses, in more modern frameworks). There is no need to be narrow-minded about labels. Secondly, the two example sentences are not just unambiguously ungrammatical. More needs to be said.

Comment: @RichardZ Post-modification is not even an inherent function of an adjective. Generally, you can't postmodify a noun with a single adjective. *_She's a girl pretty._ Rather, it's an inherent function of a phrase/clause. _She's a girl_ [_pretty and innocuous_]. _She's a girl_ [_who is pretty and innocuous_]. _She's the only girl_ [_in our class_].  _She's the only girl_ [_who is in our class_]. So _who is in our class_ is no less of "an adjective clause" than _in our class_ is "an adjective phrase."

Comment: I guess when traditional grammarians coined the term “adjective clause”, they weren’t thinking of POST modification of a noun, but just modification of a noun in general. At any rate, the term still exists as such.

Comment: @RichardZ Show me a clause that pre-modifies a noun, because there's none that I can think of right now. Unless you do, I doubt that traditional grammarians were even "thinking" when they coined the term 'adjective clause'.

Comment: How about: The “British-is-best” mentality.

Comment: And traditional grammarians did in fact put a lot of thought into their terms. I refer you to “The Report of the Joint Committee on Gramatical Terminology.” (p. 13 in the revised 1911 edition).

Comment: @RichardZ Do you really think “British-is-best” is a clause? Give me a break. The very reason you'd need hyphens or double quotes--although you have used both, you can get away with either, but you can't with neither--between the words is to make it a single word. Otherwise, it cannot pre-modify the noun 'mentality'.

Comment: Look, this is getting out of hand. Of course “British-is-best” is a clause - it has a subject and a predicate (would you really analyze the phrase as “a single word” - that would not be a very insightful analysis). But no matter how you label this form of modification, “adjective clause” is a legitimate term, see work in traditional grammar. I suggest you accept this fact and we can move on...

Comment: @RichardZ Traditional grammars, especially their terms, are mostly based on Latin grammar. And we're not talking about Latin but English. And English in the 21st century, not back in the 19th century or early 20th century. Just because it's "traditional" doesn't mean it's "legitimate" when numerous grammarians came up with a much better "modern" grammar with the aid of computers/Internet/corpus data. It's high time you abandon the traditional grammar. But it's up to you, so I won't suggest you do anything. Just don't suggest I do anything either.

Comment: Your personal preference for one linguistic term or another does not constitute an argument as to why it should be used. We can stop here, or move this discussion to a chat.

Comment: @RichardZ It's not a matter of personal preference that you try to make it seem to be. It's rebelling against an anachronistic, outdated, illogical grammar. If it's merely a matter of personal preference, there should be as many current distinguished grammarians who "prefer" the traditional grammar, but there aren't. In fact, there is not a single current grammarian that prefers the traditional grammar that I know of. But yes, let's stop here. I know you wouldn't admit to it anyway. – JK2 6 mins ago